# Creating simple CSS multilevel menu

Tags: css

I am trying to make a webpage with a navigation functionality EXACTLY like this one: http://www.rex-ny.com/ where you click a list item and its children items appear and stay.

I can do it with hover, but I can't figure out how to make it stay when not hovering.

It seems like the most simple thing is the most difficult to do.

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/phzuC/

Comment: Can you pst a fiddle of your hovering example and then one of us will maybe make it clickable

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/phzuC/

Comment: @user2730793 That won't work. As soon as you let go of the mouse, the menu disappears.

Comment: @ninty9notout I know it won't work. I just don't know what else to do!

Comment: @user2730793 see the answer below!

Comment: rex-ny.com displays sub-menu items after navigating to a different URI, not using CSS or JS.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a CSS only solution as the OP requested, using `tabindex`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/phzuC/2/

```
#menu li > ul {
    display:none;
}

#menu li:focus > ul {
    display:block;
}
li {
    outline: 0; 
}
```

**EDITED**

Here is a jQuery solution should you ever need it. It keeps the submenus open and it's simple to implement. 11 lines of code.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/phzuC/5/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-top > li").click(function(e) {
  if($(this).find('ul').hasClass('expanded')) {
      $(this).find('ul').removeClass('expanded').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('expanded').show();
  }
  });
  $('.nav-top a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: This dude's a genius!

Comment: You should probably remove the href attribute from the "Menu *" buttons. Also this will stop working after clicking the inner links.

Comment: This is a good solution. OP will have to compromise with it hiding as soon as the first-level link loses focus, but to re-utter @TheApptracker's words, that's genius!

Comment: It would be great if it didn't hide... but I will try this for now and maybe JS later on...

Comment: thanks, I've added a simple quick jQuery solution if you ever need it. It may suit your needs better in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another CSS only solution that uses either:

- Checkboxes if you want the menus to toggle on click
- radio buttons if you want the menus to auto close when another is selected

Reference:

- [CSSTricks: Stuff you can do with the “Checkbox Hack”](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)
- [The CSS Ninja: CSS Tree](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/css_tree/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wTCEM/2/)

Basic behavior CSS (the demo has more styling to remove the default list indentation/bullets):

```
.sideMenu input[type='radio'], 
.sideMenu input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
}
.sideMenu input[type='radio'] + ul, 
.sideMenu input[type='checkbox'] + ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
.sideMenu input[type='radio']:checked + ul, 
.sideMenu input[type='checkbox']:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML (can be arbitrarily deep):

```
<nav class="sideMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="menu1">Menu 1</label>
            <input id="menu1" type="checkbox" name="menu1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- repeat -->
   </ul>
</nav>
```