# Making "Drop Down Menu" and "Head Menu" relative does not make de "Drop Down Menu" push down the "Head Menu" on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

So again I am strugling with some problems. This time it is so that when I hover over the drop down menu from portfoilio (when the site is in mobile view mode) it will just go over the other elements, I tried making everything relative, removed the float and tried numerous other of things but nothing seemed to work. I want to prevent putting a margin under the parent of the drop down menu, because if I want to add more drop downs later that I then don't have to change my codes again.

Please note that the problem is at the mobile site view not the normal site view!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the point using hover on mobile devices? They don't have it. In my oppinion you should use click. Then add another function on click for your clickable menu item and in your dropdown add another item, let's say "All". That's the way to go mobile.

Comment: Thats a good note you made their, I did not tought of that yet, I will make ir go from hover to click, but then I still have the problem of the overlapping

Comment: Try stripping your code of markup then try again. If you are not setting a height for your "toggler" wrapper, then it should overlap. There's an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520794/creating-simple-css-multilevel-menu with a fiddle attached http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/phzuC/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've set `height:30px` for `.navigation_menu > ul > li`, so of course that's the only space that will be occupied.

Changing that to `line-height:30px` is all that it takes to solve this problem. You can [see it in action here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVLomV). There are more 'elegant' ways of implementing such menu but that's a totally different matter and this isn't the place to talk about that.

Of course, this doesn't change the fact that there's no 'hover' for mobile (sometimes first tap is considered hover and second tap is click but if you have a link, the first tap can act as a click event). There's some jQuery scripts [such as this](https://github.com/xodigital/jQuery-touchMenuHover) which solves that problem.

Comment: Thanks, so stupid that I could not find that myself, but anyways the open on click is not so hard to fix but your comment about that there are way more elegant ways to make a menu made me curious, is there an other place where I could ask you about that?

Comment: You're welcome! If you think that has answered your question, please mark it as the answer (the checkmark below upvote/downvote). For the normal view, I think the dropdown should be absolute-positioned with the 1st level `ul` being set with `inline-block` so that you can place logo, search input etc. at the header. Applying padding for header just to 'fake' the space seems 'hackish' and might appear 'broken' if the condition is not favourable (e.g. if the menu breaks into 2 lines).